# Getting error while reading data from firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm using angularfire2 to add and fetch data from firestore and i have kept read and write open.The problem is i'm able to write to the database but i'm not getting an error while fetching data :

```
Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction
```

Here is the code i'm using

```
clientsCollection:AngularFirestoreCollection<UserLogs>;
clientDocs:AngularFirestoreDocument<UserLogs>;
  clients:Observable<UserLogs[]>;
  client:Observable<UserLogs>
  constructor(private afs : AngularFirestore) {
    this.clientsCollection = afs.collection<UserLogs>('logindb');
    this.clients=this.clientsCollection.valueChanges();
    console.log(this.clients);

   }

newClient(client:UserLogs)
{
  this.clientsCollection.add(client).catch(err =>{
    console.log(err);


  });
}
```